# How to deal with character collision on corners in Flutter Flame

Tags: flutter, game-physics, flame

I am trying to create little top view game with a character that moves around an open world. The world is filled with obstacles. I cannot figure out to handle my character position when he collides with corners of obstacles. I have the following onCollision method implemented, which ofcourse works just fine when the player hits a wall vertically or horizontally.

```
  @override
  void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, PositionComponent other) {
    if (other is Wall) {
      if (intersectionPoints.length == 2) {
        var pointA = intersectionPoints.elementAt(0);
        var pointB = intersectionPoints.elementAt(1);
        final mid = (pointA + pointB) / 2;
        final collisionVector = absoluteCenter - mid;
        double penetrationDepth = (size.x / 2) - collisionVector.length;
        collisionVector.normalize();
        position += collisionVector.scaled(penetrationDepth);
      }
    }
    super.onCollision(intersectionPoints, other);
  }
```

However, when the character hits a corner, the way the penetration depth is calculated does not make sense, and therefor he gets stuck.

[image]

Any help on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by figuring out how the intersection points work and determining the quadrant of the collision vector's direction.
The smallest absolute displacement in either x or y direction determines from which side the player bumps into the corner. It works, so I am happy :).
Still very curious if a math wizz could do this without all these assumptions, and use some clever vector tricks.

```
  @override
  void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, PositionComponent other) {
    if (other is Wall) {
      if (intersectionPoints.length == 2) {
        var pointA = intersectionPoints.elementAt(0);
        var pointB = intersectionPoints.elementAt(1);
        final mid = (pointA + pointB) / 2;
        final collisionVector = absoluteCenter - mid;
        if (pointA.x == pointB.x || pointA.y == pointB.y) {
          // Hitting a side without touching a corner
          double penetrationDepth = (size.x / 2) - collisionVector.length;
          collisionVector.normalize();
          position += collisionVector.scaled(penetrationDepth);
        } else {
          position += _cornerBumpDistance(collisionVector, pointA, pointB);
        }
      }
    }
    super.onCollision(intersectionPoints, other);
  }

  Vector2 _cornerBumpDistance(
      Vector2 directionVector, Vector2 pointA, Vector2 pointB) {
    var dX = pointA.x - pointB.x;
    var dY = pointA.y - pointB.y;
    // The order of the two intersection points differs per corner
    // The following if statements negates the necessary values to make the 
    // player move back to the right position
    if (directionVector.x > 0 && directionVector.y < 0) {
      // Top right corner
      dX = -dX;
    } else if (directionVector.x > 0 && directionVector.y > 0) {
      // Bottom right corner 
      dX = -dX;
    } else if (directionVector.x < 0 && directionVector.y > 0) {
      // Bottom left corner
      dY = -dY;
    } else if (directionVector.x < 0 && directionVector.y < 0) {
      // Top left corner
      dY = -dY;
    }
    // The absolute smallest of both values determines from which side the player bumps
    // and therefor determines the needed displacement
    if (dX.abs() < dY.abs()) {
      return Vector2(dX, 0);
    } else {
      return Vector2(0, dY);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First time I try something for the game in Flutter. Could you please try this code for your need?

```
@override
void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, PositionComponent other) {
  if (other is Wall) {
    if (intersectionPoints.length == 2) {
      final wallCorner = intersectionPoints.elementAt(0);
      final collisionVector = position - wallCorner;
      final penetrationDepth = size.x / 2 - collisionVector.length;
      collisionVector.normalize();
      position += collisionVector * penetrationDepth;
    }
  }
  super.onCollision(intersectionPoints, other);
}
```